# Winapi Window in c not responding

Tags: c, windows, winapi, window, cl

I've been trying to make a simple window using WinAPI, it compiles and links with some warnings, when I open the program the window shows up, but when I try to interact with it, a windows warning sound is played and it doesn't allow me to use the window, not even close it, I have to use task manager.

To compile it I'm using Microsoft's "cl.exe" with the command line:

```
cl /c window.c
```

and the warnings are:

```
window.c(39): warning C4133: 'function': incompatible types, from 'LPSTR' to 'HINSTANCE'
window.c(40): warning C4133: 'function': incompatible types, from 'LPSTR' to 'HINSTANCE'
window.c(41): warning C4047: '=': 'HBRUSH' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
```

To link I use [crinkler](https://github.com/runestubbe/Crinkler) with the commandline:

```
crinkler /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:main /SUSBYSTEM:WINDOWS /TINYHEADER /TINYIMPORT /OUT:c.exe window.obj kernel32.lib user32.lib
```

and the warning is:

```
: warning LNK: Entry point not at start of section, jump necessary
```

The code I'm using is:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define WINDOW_STYLE        WS_VISIBLE+WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW-WS_THICKFRAME-WS_MAXIMIZE
#define WINDOW_WIDTH        640
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT       480

static const char* window_name = "My Window";
RECT window_rect = {0, 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcA(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    int ret = 0;
    HMODULE instance = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);

    AdjustWindowRect(&window_rect, WINDOW_STYLE, FALSE);

    WNDCLASSEXA window_class;
    window_class.cbSize = 48;
    window_class.style = CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    window_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
    window_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
    window_class.hInstance = instance;
    window_class.hIcon = LoadIconA(IDI_APPLICATION, 0);
    window_class.hCursor = LoadCursorA(IDI_APPLICATION, 0);
    window_class.hbrBackground = COLOR_WINDOW;
    window_class.lpszMenuName = 0;
    window_class.lpszClassName = window_name;
    window_class.hIconSm = 0;

    if (RegisterClassExA(&window_class)) {

        HWND window = CreateWindowExA(
            0,
            window_name,
            window_name,
            WINDOW_STYLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            window_rect.right - window_rect.left,
            window_rect.bottom - window_rect.top,
            0,
            0,
            instance,
            NULL);

        ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(window);

        MSG msg;

        while(1)
        {
            if (PeekMessageA(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
                    ExitProcess(0);
                    break;
                } else {
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        ret = 1;
    }

    ExitProcess(0);

    return ret;
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Your message loop should use `GetMessage()` instead of `PeekMessage()`. You are running a busy loop eating up CPU cycles during times when your app has no messages to process. Using `GetMessage()` will allow the app to sleep when it has nothing to do. Also, don't use ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) - use `sizeof(window_class)` when setting `window_class.cbSize`. And you are getting an `HBRUSH` warning because you are setting `window_class.hbrBackground` incorrectly. Use `window_class.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);`, per the documentation

Comment: Here is an example of [handling WM_CLOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/closing-the-window)   There are lots of other examples online for the things you want to do

Comment: @use That's not useful. The OP isn't using the CRT, so they cannot rely on it to perform process shutdown. Without the CRT, responsibility to trigger process shutdown has shifted to client code. The code presented does just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line doesn't do what you think it does:

```c
#define WINDOW_STYLE WS_VISIBLE+WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW-WS_THICKFRAME-WS_MAXIMIZE
```

While somewhat common, and occasionally even producing the correct value, it is a very brittle way to implement bit manipulations. In this particular case, the expression expands to:

```
0x10000000L + 0x00CF0000L - 0x00040000L - 0x01000000L
```

This produces the value `0xFFCB0000L`<sup>1</sup> (due to accidentally using `WS_MAXIMIZE` instead of `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`). This translates to a window with the following styles:

- `WS_POPUP`
- `WS_CHILD` (note, that this is already mutually exclusive with `WS_POPUP`)
- `WS_ICONIC`
- `WS_VISIBLE`
- `WS_DISABLED`
- ...

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles):

> `WS_DISABLED`: The window is initially disabled. **A disabled window cannot receive input from the user.** To change this after a window has been created, use the `EnableWindow` function.

That explains why you cannot interact with your window. The fix is simple: Use bitwise operators for bit manipulations instead of arithmetic operators:

```c
#define WINDOW_STYLE (WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_THICKFRAME & ~WS_MAXIMIZE)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Leaving the fact, that the behavior for signed overflow is undefined aside.*